# sorting in python considering output constraints

Tags: python-2.7

I want to imitate normal ls command in python using os.listdir(),

and want the output same as ls.

i.e. 
considering number of file/directory to be printed in one line, and vertical alphabetical sorting etc.

How should i sort list produced by os.listdir() considering given constraints?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted()`:

```
import os 
print len(os.listdir("/Users/alfasi")) # print the number of files
for f in sorted(os.listdir("<your-directory>")):
    print f
```

Comment: My problem is when i use simple sorting it just sort alphabatically.

but ls command sort according to screen size by number of rows needed for printing and then sorting vertically

Comment: @AkhilBatra I never heard anything about  sorting according to screen-size. Do you have a reference (link) ?

Comment: ls does a column base printing of files and diectory, and number of column depends on size of string(file or dir names), and simultaneously it prints them in alphabetical order start from first column rwo by row till last column...
That's what i want to implement

Answer (score 0):

Are you opposed to using the real `ls` command?

```
import os
print os.system('ls')
```

should give you exactly what you want.

Apart from that, I take "sorted by screen size" to mean that you want everything displayed on one line, wrapped the same way `ls` does. You can accomplish that, more or less, like this:

```
import os
import textwrap
textwrap.fill("\t".join(os.listdir('<your dir>')), break_on_hyphens=False)
```

Comment: i can't use os.system(), That's a precondition for the task assigned to me.
and second solution does not give tabular printing and it is giving sorted list in one row and ls gives it column-wise.